# Weird Python subprocess quoting behavior

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I wanted to use use subprocess.Popen, because my program sets up a bunch of command line parameters and environment variables for the program to be executed.

```
import subprocess, os
s = r'-a"abc\def"'
x = ['cmd', '/c', 'echo', s ]
y = ' '.join( x )
print('y: ', y )
os.system( y )
print('x: ', x )
print('cmdline: ', subprocess.list2cmdline( x ))
subprocess.call( x, shell=False )
subprocess.call( x, shell=True )
subprocess.Popen( x )
```

But the above (reduced) program shows that if there are embedded quotation marks in one or more of the parameters, that the command line processing done by subprocess is incorrect, whereas os.system works fine.  Is there a solution? I couldn't find one in the subprocess docs: the example showing how to convert os.system to subprocess has this same problem, AFAICT. (The problem here is the added \ before the " characters.)

Windows 10, Python 3.8.0

Comment: try converting s from `s = r'-a"abc\def"'` to `s = r'\'-a"abc\def"\''`

Comment: @AlbinPaul Thanks for the idea, but I guess you hadn't tried it, or you wouldn't have suggested it.